# Having trouble adding a "custom" field to a Devise registration form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, strong-parameters

I'm working on adding an "account plan" select field to a Devise sign-up form.

My user model is called `User` and my account plan model is called `AccountPlan`. Since the majority of users are expected to not actually be accountholders, `User` is connected to `AccountPlan` via `PaidAccount`, i.e. `User` has one `AccountPlan` through `PaidAccount`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :paid_account
  has_one :account_plan, through: :paid_account
end
```

And then here's the relevant part of my form:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { id: "payment-form" }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :account_plan, @account_plans, :id, :name_with_price %>
<% end %>
```

My problem is that when I submit the form (which was working perfectly up until I added the `:account_plan` field), I get

> undefined method `id' for "2":String

It tells me that the offending line is `super`, which is of course not particularly helpful. I figured out that the offending line is [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L13), so it evidently doesn't like something about the params.

The confusing thing, though, is that if I do `User.new(account_plan: AccountPlan.new)` on the console, it takes that just fine. So if my form is spitting out this HTML

```
<select id="user_account_plan" name="user[account_plan]"><option value="2">Lite ($10.00/mo)</option>
  <option value="3">Professional ($20.00/mo)</option>
  <option value="4">Plus ($30.00/mo)</option>
</select>
```

then I don't get what the problem should be.

If it helps, here's my controller code:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    @account_plans = AccountPlan.order(:price)
    super
  end

  def create
    super
    Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe_secret_key
    Stripe::Customer.create(
      card: params[:stripeToken],
      description: resource.email
    )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing the `PaidAccount` contains a lot of extra attributes for a paid-account, including aspecification of the account-plan, which is a list of available plans. So your relation should look like

```
class PaidAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account_plan
end
```

(which means that the `PaidAccount` has a attribute `account_plan_id`)

There are two approaches: use a nested form, or use something more ad hoc.

#### Using a nested form

I am using `simple_form` and `haml` --> please check into that, makes the code a lot easier to write and show :)

So in that case, I would do the following:

```
class User 
  has_one :paid_account
  has_one :account_plan, through: :paid_account

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :paid_account
end
```

Because we are not creating a new `account_plan`, we are linking to an existing one.

Your form would simply become:

```
= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { id: "payment-form" }) do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :paid_account do |pa|
    = pa.association :account_plan
```

The problem with this approach: when do you create the `paid_account`, a bit hard to tell without seeing the rest of your code. I see two options:

- you only want to create it when an account-plan is chosen.
- or you allow users only to select an account-plan, when they already have decided to be paying (and you can already create the `PaidAccount` object).

I am guessing it is the first option. For the nested form to work, you will always have to create the nested `PaidAccount` and delete it when saving when the account-plan is not filled in. That is actually easy to do, so we add

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :paid_account, reject_if: :blank
```

And your controller `new` action should become:

```
  def new
    @account_plans = AccountPlan.order(:price)
    build_resource({})
    resource.build_paid_account 
    respond_with self.resource
  end
```

Also note you will have to correctly specify your strong parameters, so your `permits` should look something like

```
    def post_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :paid_account_attributes => [:account_path_id])
    end
```

#### The more ad hoc approach

- use the view as you had before
- allow the `account_plan` in your `post_params` (as above)
- check the value of `account_plan` in the create action, and build a `PaidAccount` with the correct account plan if needed.

So your `create` action would look like

```
def create
  account_plan_id = params[:user].delete(:account_plan)
  super
  if account_plan_id.present?
    resource.build_paid_account(account_plan_id: account_plan_id)
  end
  Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe_secret_key
  Stripe::Customer.create(
    card: params[:stripeToken],
    description: resource.email
  )
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. You read my mind in several places! I took your suggestion to use simple_form, but the `<%= pa.association :account_plan %>` part is not outputting any HTML nor showing any errors. Any ideas there?

Comment: Nevermind; I figured that part out. The base Devise `RegistrationsController` was doing a `respond_with self.resource` and so anything I put after `super` was not running. I copied the two lines of code from the original `RegistrationsController`, put them in mine, added `self.resource.build_paid_account` before the `respond_with`, and my select field started showing up.

Comment: And the form now submits without errors but my user is not actually getting an `account_plan` record.

Comment: Ah, and I think it's because I'm probably doing the sanitization wrong.

Comment: Okay, I'm still stuck but I accepted your answer because it got me past the biggest problems I was having. At this point it's probably best for me to start a separate question for the issue I'm having now.

Comment: And if you're interested, here's the other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21888960/confused-about-strong-parameters-with-devise

Comment: Ok, I see it is answered. Great you got it working. How did you fix the missing `_attributes`? I would assume in the `fields_for` you need to give the relation-name.

Comment: I did it like this, but as you can see I'm not totally satisfied with the solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891120/is-there-a-better-way-to-name-this-field-appropriately

Answer (score 1):

I think you have 2 problems there:

- in the collection_select use :account_plan_id as the method for your object
- you have to "sanitize" your params (because of the strong parameters in Rails 4- read more here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters) for additional fields with devise. So in your registrations_controller add the accepted params like:

  def sign_up_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :account_plan_id and whatever else you need in registration )
    end

Comment: The `user` has no `account_plan_id` attribute. OP uses the `has_one` relation, so `paid_account` has the `user_id` and I assume also the `account_plan_id` field.

Comment: @sissy, I think you're right about the sanitization. I am actually doing that already, I just neglected to mention it in my question.

Comment: I asked a different question which you might know the answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21888960/confused-about-strong-parameters-with-devise

Comment: No problem! Your answer was still helpful.