# Confused about strong parameters with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, strong-parameters

I have the following Devise registration form (with irrelevant markup omitted):

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { id: "payment-form" }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for resource.paid_account do |pa| %>
    <%= pa.collection_select :account_plan_id, @account_plans, :id, :name_with_price %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This form spits out the following HTML:

```
<select id="user_paid_account_account_plan_id" name="user[paid_account][account_plan_id]">
  <option value="2">Lite ($10.00/mo)</option>
  <option value="3">Professional ($20.00/mo)</option>
  <option value="4">Plus ($30.00/mo)</option>
</select>
```

I then have the following code in my `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(
        :email,
        :password,
        :paid_account => :account_plan_id # <-- THIS IS PROBABLY WRONG
      )
    end
  end
end
```

When I submit my form I get "PaidAccount(#2163736620) expected, got ActionController::Parameters(#2173083140)".

I've also tried the following which doesn't give an error, but it also doesn't create a record:

```
  u.permit(
    :email,
    :password,
    :paid_account => []
  )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: to me also it didn't work the way you're trying, i had to put the sanitization inside the Devise RegistrationController like:

`def sign_up_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, ....)
    end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing your two models (`User` and `PaidAccount`, I believe) would help a great deal. Regardless, assuming `User` has a one-to-one relationship with `PaidAccount`, the code should probably look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :paid_account

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :paid_account
end

class PaidAcount < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(
        :email,
        :password,
        :paid_account_attributes => :account_plan_id
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Look at your logs to see how the form values are being submitted. The docs of the [StrongPameters gem](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#readme) and [Active Record's Nested Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) should also be helpful.

Comment: Your answer is right. It turns out part of the problem was that my form was naming the `paid_account` field without the `_attributes` part, which was throwing everything off.