# Is there a better way to name this field appropriately?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have the following form code (irrelevant parts omitted):

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { id: "payment-form" }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for resource.paid_account do |pa| %>
    <%= pa.collection_select :account_plan_id, @account_plans, :id, :name_with_price, {},
                             { name: "user[paid_account_attributes][account_plan_id]" } %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You can see the dumb part on the 4th line: I'm hard-coding the name to `user[paid_account_attributes][account_plan_id]`. If I don't do that, the name it gets is `user[paid_account][account_plan_id]`, which doesn't fly on the back-end.

The way I'm doing it works, but it feels like a hack. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: You've added accepts_nested_attributes_for :paid_account in your model? It should do it automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2nd line remove `resource.` and put `:paid_account` only

```
<%= f.fields_for :paid_account do |pa| %>
```

Comment: I tried that but then it's not scoped to `resource`, which I need it to be.

Comment: have you added `accepts_nested_attributes_for :paid_account` in the model?

Comment: Disregard my last comment - you're right. I was somehow mistaken. Thanks.